# Upgrading natty version of ubuntu

Tags: linux

I am trying to upgrade my version, which is natty(11.04). Since no more support is available I changed the sources.list as follows.

```
 # EOL upgrade sources.list
 # Required
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse

 # Optional
 #deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main universe restricted multiverse
 #deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse


 # Optional
 #deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main universe restricted multiverse
 #deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
 deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

I included the repositories of the next version which is 11.10(oneiric).
After that I tried to run **do_release_upgrade** command.

Result :

```
 Error during update 

 A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
 network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

 W:Failed to fetch 
 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages 

 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80] 
 , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
 old ones used instead.
```

I am not getting event though archive.ubunti.com/... is not mentioned in the sources.list, why it is reffered? How can I successfully upgrade the same?

Answer (score 1):

The standard process to upgrade is 11.04 → 12.04 → 14.04.  What I do is: upgrade only once and only if direly needed.  Otherwise: re-install.

*Why?* Well, because you'll be carrying around <strike>old crap</strike> unneeded settings/programs when you upgrade resulting in a less stable system that is hard to diagnose when you eventually run into problems.

On top of that, when you upgrade, you get to test/update the documentation of your server as well!  **:-)**